# generate predefined summary c#

Tags: c#, automation, documentation

working on a gigantic project a big mistake was made that of not documenting the code
we came up with the idea of generating a predefined summary for all methods and classes
and then gradually each dev working on a file should edit the summaries he face accordingly
something like this :

```
/// <summary>
/// undocumented code please change me 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
```

so gradually everytime a developer makes some changes will have the reflex of changing it
is there a way of generating such a summary for every method
and is there a better way to propose  pls
Thank you

Comment: Check GhostDoc extension for VisualStudio: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeb.GhostDoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in visual studio that can help you with this. You can check the GhostDoc extention: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeb.GhostDoc

This feature is for pro and enterprise edition only:

> Generate missing XML comments for entire type/class, file, or project

You can possibly use the trial version to bootstrap your application and continue with the free: https://submain.com/download/ghostdoc/pro/

Afterwards you can enable the project to think of public members missing xml comments as build errors